# Deploy MVC Website as an application into MVC website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have an MVC web application deployed at the root of IIS but I have another MVC website application that needs to be deployed under the root web application. 
I tried to add the child web application via 'Add Application' under website at the root but it is unable to read web.config of the inner application and giving some assembly errors that are included in the inner web application.

Please provide me procedure how I can deploy MVC web application under the MVC website. I hope the snapshot will clear the question.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using MS Web Deploy?

Comment: No, I deployed it manually from the IIS.

Comment: What exactly is the errormessage?

Comment: Assemblies are missing that are being used in the internal MVC project and I have tested it by deploying it as a root MVC website and it was working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied assemblies in the parent site that were being used by the child web application and it then worked.

One more solution seems possible, if the child web application routes are ignored by parent site. Though I haven't tried it.